# how to get value of "active_id" for openerp kanban view

Tags: odoo, kanban

I'm creating a new module where I want to put a `button` in `kanban` view of `Contact screen`. When any user click on that `button` I need `active_id` of the selected contact. It is possible to get for tree and form view but I don't know how to do that for `kanban` view.

Can anyone please help here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `contex` dictionary variably for this purpose ,

If you click on the bu

```
<button string="Click Me" type="object" name="my_func" context="{'active' : active_id}" />
```

**Method**:

```
def my_func(self, cr, uid, ids, context={}):
    # do stuff using the info passed in the context variable...
```